# How to prove Bromwich inequality?( lower bound for inner product)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, convex-analysis

Consider Bromwhich inequality which is a generalization of the [Abel's inequality](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwjvt6_OnY3IAhVDWSwKHchVDAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhrcak.srce.hr%2Ffile%2F2823&usg=AFQjCNHhi4HSvQdI41iJYHcD-_zbnnT0rw&sig2=6qbB_qjNQHbMpDoaFYRmNg): 
Theorem : For a given real n-tuple $p$ and given integer $v(1\le v\le n)$, define $H_1=h_1=0$, $H_v=\max(P_1,...P_{v-1}$,$h_v=\min(P_1,...,P_{v-1})$ and $H_{v}^{'}=\max(P_v,...P_n)$,$h_v^{'}=\min(P_v,...,P_n)$, where $P_k=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i$. If $a$ is a positive , nonincreasing n-tuple then

$h_v(a_1-a_v)+h_v^{'} a_v \le \sum_{i=1}^n p_i a_i \le H_v(a_1-a_v)+H_v^{'} a_v$.

How to prove this inequality?

Is there any theorem for the case in which $a$ is not positive?

All variables are real.

Comment: Should it perhaps be *Bromwhich* rather than *Bromwich*?

Comment: Yes. I edit it. Thank you.